# How can I use pyspark to give every item of an array column its own column named like [original_column_name]_[original_pos_in_array]?

Tags: python, pyspark

How can I use pyspark to give every item of an array column its own column named like [original_column_name]_[original_pos_in_array]?

For example, if I have this Dataframe:

```
data = [
    ("A", ["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5"], ["6"]),
    ("B", ["7", "8"], ["9"], ["10", "11", "12"]),
    ("C", ["13", "14", "15"], ["16", "17"], ["18", "19"]),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["col1", "array_col1", "array_col2", "array_col3"])
```

How can I transform it to this:

[image]

My approach looks like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import posexplode, col

# Assume that "df" is a DataFrame that contains one or more array columns
# Use "posexplode" to explode all the array columns into multiple columns
array_cols = [c for c, t in df.dtypes if "array" in t]
exprs = [f"posexplode({c}) as ({c}_pos, {c})" for c in array_cols]
exploded_df = df.selectExpr("id", *exprs)

# Determine the maximum length of each array column
max_lengths = [exploded_df.selectExpr(f"max(size({c})) as max_length").collect()[0]["max_length"] for c in array_cols]

# Generate expressions for each array column separately
col_exprs = []
for i, c in enumerate(array_cols):
    col_expr = [f"coalesce({c}[{j+1}], '') as {c}_{j}" for j in range(max_lengths[i])]
    col_exprs.append(",".join(col_expr))

# Combine expressions using "selectExpr"
exprs = [f"{c}_pos" if c in array_cols else c for c in exploded_df.columns] + col_exprs
indexed_df = exploded_df.selectExpr(*exprs)

# Show the result
indexed_df.show()
```

The error is that I have to many generators in the Select-Clause